# Codeship command runs very long after it is finished

Tags: node.js, codeship

I have the following codeship-steps.yml

```
# test
- name: test
  type: serial
  services:
  - build
  steps:
  - command: npm test
```

What I experience is that even if the command is finished the step runs ahead for 1 or 2 minutes without doing anything or go to the next step/group. Does anybody experience same thing, what can I do here?
Even if I just do `npm -v` this sometimes take 3 minutes, thats weird, isn't it?

Comment: Hey Moritz, did you create a support ticket on https://helpdesk.codeship.com including a link to the build in question so we can look into this?

Comment: not yet. good idea to do so, thanks!